# Web API Request Data error on second time

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Strange Error.

```
var xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);

var xmlDoc1 = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmlDoc1.Load(this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
```

In `WEB API`, I try to load the `POST` data in to `xmlXoc` it is working good

When I try to load it again in to `xmlDoc1` (new variable), I am getting a `Root Element missing` error.

I see that `ReadAsStreamAsync` is a `Read-Only-Stream` but why the error on the last line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the `Stream` in a local variable and reset it to the beginning when reading it a second time.

```
var stream = this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result

var xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(stream);

// RESET 
stream.Position = 0;
var xmlDoc1 = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
xmlDoc1.Load(stream);
```

Comment: Thanks :) So, we have to set its position to 0 so that we would be able to read it again.. Now understood ..